# Avoid Data Race condition in swift

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

I am getting race conditions in my code when I run TSan tool. As same code has been accessed from different queues and threads at the same time that's why I can not use Serial queues or barrier as Queue will block only single queues accessing the shared resource not the other queues.

I used `objc_sync_enter(object) | objc_sync_exit(object)` and locks `NSLock() or NSRecursiveLock()` to protect shared resource but these are also not working.

While when I use `@synchronized()` keyword in Objective C to protect shared resource, it's working fine as expected and I am not getting race conditions in particular block of code.

So, what is an alternative to protect data in Swift as we can not use `@synchronized()` keyword in Swift language.

PFA screenshot for reference -
[image: Data Race]

Comment: What other places is `self.moments` being accessed?

Comment: It has been accessed from different classes.

Comment: try sending some flags :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't understand "I can not use Serial queues or barrier as Queue will block only single queues accessing the shared resource not the other queues." Using a queue is the standard solution to this problem.

```
class MultiAccess {
    private var _property: String = ""
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "MultiAccess")
    var property: String {
        get {
            var result: String!
            queue.sync {
                result = self._property
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            queue.async {
                self._property = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this construction, access to `property` is atomic and thread-safe without the caller having to do anything special. Note that this intentionally uses a single queue for the class, not a queue per-property. As a rule, you want a relatively small number of queues doing a lot of work, not a large number of queues doing a little work. If you find that you're accessing a mutable object from lots of different threads, you need to rethink your system (probably reducing the number of threads). There's no simple pattern that will make that work efficiently and safely without you having to think about your specific use case carefully.

But this construction is useful for problems where system frameworks may call you back on random threads with minimal contention. It is simple to implement and fairly easy to use correctly. If you have a more complex problem, you will have to design a solution for that problem.

---

Edit: I haven't thought about this answer in a long time, but Brennan's comments brought it back to my attention. Because of the bug I had in the original code, my original answer was ok, but if you fixed the bug it was bad. (If you want to see my original code that used a barrier, look in the edit history, I don't want to put it here because people will copy it.) I've changed it to use a standard serial queue rather than a concurrent queue.

Don't generate concurrent queues without careful thought about how threads will be generated. If you are going to have many simultaneous accesses, you're going to create a lot of threads, which is bad. If you're not going to have many simultaneous accesses, then you don't need a concurrent queue. GCD talks make promises about managing threads that it doesn't actually live up to. You definitely can get thread explosion (as Brennan mentions.)

Comment: I tried the same approach for it's fix. But is this the right way when we have several properties in a class?

Comment: Yes. In many cases it is reasonable to have a single queue for the entire class rather than one queue per property. It depends on the performance requirements. Keep in mind that if multiple values are mutable, there may be additional race conditions due to changes in one property that are not synchronized with changes in other properties. In any case, this is the correct foundation; the precise implementation just depends on what kind of atomic behavior you need.

Comment: Yes. Because other approaches are not working in my case.

Comment: @RobNapier I have had to eliminate this pattern within properties due to thread explosion. Note: the text mentions a concurrent queue while the code show a serial queue so I assume the code is wrong since the barrier flag is used. What happens is a value is set and then many observer are notified which then immediately call the getter while the async work is still not done. I found this leads to many threads being blocked for each of the observers. Now I avoid this pattern in properties entirely. I believe once you move to the next line after setting a property the value should be set.

Comment: @Brennan "What happens is a value is set and then many observer are notified which then immediately call the getter while the async work is still not done." This is likely the problem. I would redesign so that observers receive the new value rather than just "something changed." Thank you for catching the lack of `.concurrent` bug. It got me rethinking about this answer and I've edited it.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the update. What I found more devious about this bug is the implicit contract with a setter. It expected the the getter can be used immediately after the assignment of the property. That async call breaks the contract. When I found this pattern I eliminated the property with a function with a closer which is run once the value is set. The closure was used notify observers which worked much better.

Comment: @Brennan That doesn't sound correct. With the barrier, you should be promised that any getter that comes after a setter will see the setter's value. If you're not seeing that, then something is wrong, since that's the point of a barrier. My point of not using a getter immediately after a setter was for performance, not correctness. If you're seeing correctness problems, then something is wrong. (My original bug should not have caused this, because it was a fully serialized queue.)